# how to make text shadow effect in pillow python?

Tags: python, image-processing, text, python-imaging-library

So far I have achieved [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knONq.jpg) with the pillow, but it's not much visible on some photos, so I want to add some shadow behind the image(called lift effect in texts) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q154D.jpg)
which is basically the addition of two texts, one with a blur version  and the second is normal text on top with a little smaller size (please check the second image to understand)
I can't find anywhere about how to blur the text, so would be really nice if someone can help me out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not 100% certain what you have to start with or what you really want to end up with, but here is a technique that can give you a soft shadow behind text. Basically, you do the following:

- create a spare piece of canvas big enough for your text
- write your text on the canvas
- blur it to soften it
- paste that onto the original image
- write the sharp text on top

There are a million variations, with different type of blur, different font sizes, different under-colours (shadow colours) and different ways of pasting/compositing the blurred text onto the original. But if you take the code below as a starting point you can experiment till you are happy.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# See also: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/fonts/#soft_shadow
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter, ImageChops

# Open background image and work out centre
bg = Image.open('bg.png').convert('RGB')
x = bg.width//2
y = bg.height//2

# The text we want to add
text = "StackOverflow"

# Create font
font = ImageFont.truetype('/System/Library/Fonts/MarkerFelt.ttc', 60)

# Create piece of canvas to draw text on and blur
blurred = Image.new('RGBA', bg.size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(blurred)
draw.text(xy=(x,y), text=text, fill='cyan', font=font, anchor='mm')
blurred = blurred.filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(7))

# Paste soft text onto background
bg.paste(blurred,blurred)

# Draw on sharp text
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(bg)
draw.text(xy=(x,y), text=text, fill='navy', font=font, anchor='mm')
bg.save('result.png')
```

**Original image**

[image]

**Result image**

[image]