# How to increase a shadow on an Image with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

here's my issue.
I'm trying to add a shadow on a image, i have the image of the shadow where every pixels are 1 or 0 in RGB. Only the Alpha number is different. The lowest alpha, the darker is the shadow.
I did this

```
def print_shadow(im, shadow):
  im_pix = np.array(im)
  shadow_pix = np.array(shadow)
  shadow_pix[:, :, :3] = 1
  shadow_pix = np.multiply(shadow_pix, -1)
  shadow_pix = np.add(255, shadow_pix)
  shadow_pix = np.divide(shadow_pix, 255)
  im_pix = np.multiply(im_pix, shadow_pix)
  im_pix = np.array(im_pix).astype(np.uint8)
  return Image.fromarray(im_pix)
```

This function work perfectly but we're comming to the issue. I tried to add a factor to make the shadow darker or brigther.
I tried to add a line (line 4)

```
def print_shadow(im, shadow, factor):
  im_pix = np.array(im)
  shadow_pix = np.array(shadow)
  shadow_pix[:, :, :3] = 1
  shadow_pix = np.divide(shadow_pix, factor)
  shadow_pix = np.multiply(shadow_pix, -1)
  shadow_pix = np.add(255, shadow_pix)
  shadow_pix = np.divide(shadow_pix, 255)
  im_pix = np.multiply(im_pix, shadow_pix)
  im_pix = np.array(im_pix).astype(np.uint8)
  return Image.fromarray(im_pix)
```

But it doesn't just increase the darkness of the shadow. Tt puts like a dark filter on the whole image, even where there's no shadow.
Can someone help me ? I don't understand what's happening

Comment: You don't really need alpha for this.  If you have an array from 0 to 1, just take `np.ones` minus that array, duplicate it into three channels, and multiply the original image by that.  Where you multiply by 1, the pixels stay the same.  Where you multiply by 0.5, the image gets 50% darker.

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67473444/how-to-make-text-shadow-effect-in-pillow-python

Comment: I didn't express myself well, I don't have a table that goes from 0 to 1. I have tables with only values of 0 and 1 except for the alpha